# PHP/MYSQLI how can I return a variable from a while loop inside a form to use in a $_GET request in that form's action/method?

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli, submit

I have a html form which uses a PHP while loop to populate a select menu from a MYSQLi database. Code below;

```
$query = "SELECT on_programme, last_name, first_name, middle_name, id FROM constant_client WHERE on_programme=1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

echo '<p><label for="current_clients">Select Client by name: </label>
        <select id="current_clients" name="current_clients">
        <option> -- Select Client -- </option>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          echo '<option>'.ucwords($row['last_name']).', '.ucwords($row['first_name']).' '.ucwords($row['middle_name']).'</option>';
        }
echo '</select>';
```

The above works, the form populates with the required client records. However, I am then looking to use this data to link to an individual client page, which I tried using

```
echo '&emsp;<a href="selected_client.php?id='.$row['id'].'" onClick="this.form.submit()">Go!</a>';
```

which did not work, so I tried setting the form action to

```
action="selected_client.php?id='.$row['id'].'"
```

with the method as "GET", which also did not work. As you can see in the query I am selecting 'id' from the table as well so I can call on that part of the array later, I just don't particularly need or want to echo it. Using the form action method, the $row['id'] variable is not set, and using the onClick method, I get a "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" error.

I imagine that the variable needs to be set before the form action can take place, but I can't think how I would be able to do that without moving the while loop or at least returning a value from it. Is it possible to call the form method and action at submission, rather than at the top of the form? Would that make any difference at all?

Edit; as requested, my attempt at using a hidden method for the form

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';
```

Which still returns the value of type null error.

Edit #2 - all code inline.

```
$query = "SELECT on_programme, last_name, first_name, middle_name, id FROM constant_client WHERE on_programme=1 ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo  '<form action="selected_client.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>';

echo '<p><label for="current_clients">Select Client by name: </label>
        <select id="current_clients" name="current_clients">
        <option> -- Select Client -- </option>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          echo '<option>'.ucwords($row['last_name']).', '.ucwords($row['first_name']).' '.ucwords($row['middle_name']).'</option>';
        }
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'">';

echo '</fieldset></form>';
```

Comment: What the method of the form? Maybe `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . ... '">`

Comment: Form method is "get", I also tried using the hidden input with no success. Not saying you're incorrect, just that I likely don't know how to apply it properly in this situation.

Comment: Can you please show the `hidden` method attempt?

Comment: Can you do a larger scope including the `form` tags and where this resides?

Comment: Should the `current_clients` have the `id`? Looking this over again I think you want `echo '<option value="' . $row['id'] . '">' .` Then use `$_GET['current_clients']` on the next place or change the `select`s name to `id`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter which way I do it, I'm still getting the type null error. If I include the id column in the SELECT, do I HAVE to use it in the while loop? I can, I was just going to eventually have one select by last name, and then one by id, hopefully linked to the same submit button.

Comment: The `value of type null error` is in developer console or PHP error log? Can you add that error message? Is JS involved in this?

Comment: It's just in the browser output above the submit button. "Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in "project".

Comment: Your hidden field is not aware of that row ID because it is outside the loop, what you can do add onChange method to select and pass the value to some function which will get and set that hidden field with the selected value and finally submit the form to receive that on form action page.

Comment: `<select id="current_clients" name="current_clients" onChange="setId(this.value);">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add onChange event and pass the selected value to some function, in that function set the hidden field with this selected value.Now you can submit the form and your selected value can be received.Below is solution.

```
$query = "SELECT on_programme, last_name, first_name, middle_name, id FROM constant_client WHERE on_programme=1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
echo  '<form action="selected_client.php" method="get">
    <fieldset>';

echo '<p><label for="current_clients">Select Client by name: </label>
        <select id="current_clients" name="current_clients" onChange="setId(this.value);">
        <option value=""> -- Select Client -- </option>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
          echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.ucwords($row['last_name']).', '.ucwords($row['first_name']).' '.ucwords($row['middle_name']).'</option>';
        }
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="hidden_field" value="">';

echo '</fieldset></form>';
```

Add this script to set value in hidden field.

```
<script>
function setId(rowValue){
   document.getElementById("hidden_field").value=rowValue;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Adeel, that works, thanks mate. Is there a similar method with plain old PHP? I don't know anything about JS.

Comment: You are welcome @Carbs. I am afraid as PHP is server side and your requirement can only be achieved through client side therefore you have to use javascript for it and from PHP you can get this data on form submit.